# Access NFS volume mounts from Spring Boot application Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, nfs

I have added a NFS volume mount to my Spring Boot container running on Kubernetes. Below is my deployment file for Kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: ldap
spec: 
  replicas: 3
    spec: 
      serviceAccountName: xxx-staging-take-poc-admin
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-volume
          nfs:
           server: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
           path: /ifs/standard/take1-poc 
      containers: 
        - 
          image: image-id
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs-volume
              mountPath: /var/nfs
          name: ldap
```

How do I access the mount path from my Spring Boot application to achieve file read and write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can pass external info to sprint boot application through environment variables. [Here](https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-on-kubernetes-with-configm) is an article with more detailed info of how to do it.

> Kubernetes ConfigMaps also allows us to load a file as a ConfigMap
>   property. That gives us an interesting option of loading the Spring
>   Boot application.properties via Kubernetes ConfigMaps.

Also, you may want to get familiar with [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/fuse_integration_services_2.0_for_openshift/kube-spring-boot). It shows how to reference secrets which are also mounted so you may find it helpful in your case.

> The Spring Cloud Kubernetes plug-in implements the integration between
>   Kubernetes and Spring Boot. In principle, you could access the
>   configuration data from a ConfigMap using the Kubernetes API.

Please let me know if that helped.